# Delaying system shutdown during json DB update in python

Tags: python-2.7, jsondb

So I have a rather large json database that I'm maintaining with python. It's basically scraping data from a website on an hourly basis and I'm running daily restarts on the system (Linux Mint) via crontab. My issue is that if the system happens to restart during the database updating process  I get corrupted json files.

My question is if there is anyway to delay the system restart in my script to ensure the system shuts down at a safe time? I could issue the restart command inside the script itself but if I decide to run multiple scripts that are similar to this in the future I'll obviously have a problem.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: Just to clarify I'm not using the python jsondb package. I am doing all file handling myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution to this was quite simple (Just protect data integrity):
Before write - backup the file
On successful write - delete the backup (Avoids doubling the size of the DB)
Where ever a corrupted file is encountered - revert to backup
The idea being that if the system closes the script during the file backup, it doesn't matter, we still have the original and if the system closes the script during write to the original file, the backup never gets deleted and we can just use that instead. All and all it was just an extra 6 lines of code and appears to have solved the issue.